# Why is my while loop not breaking, and returning good job?

Tags: python

So I made a random number guesser, but I'm not sure why it's not working. When The number is correct, it should break the loop, and print yes.

````
import random
import math
print("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 10,what is it?")
num = random.randint(0,10)
while True:
  x = input("")
  if x == num:
    print("Good Job!")
    break
  elif x != num:
    print("Nope")```
````

Comment: What is `num`? What is `x`?

Comment: `input()` returns a string. If you compare a string to a number it will be `False`, so you need to convert the string to a number first: `x = int(input(""))`

Comment: `x` is a `str`, `num` is an `int`. `x == num` is always `False`.

Comment: There's no point  if`elif` really, just `else` suffices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string with int. Convert user input (string) to int and then compare.

You can convert using `int(x) == num`.

One more thing, `randint(0,10)` will also return `0`, you need to use `random.randint(1,10)`.

Live example:

```html
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/unstable/pyscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />


<div id="out"></div>
<py-script output="out" style="display: none">
import random
import math
print("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 10,what is it?")
num = random.randint(1,10)

while True:
  x = input("")
  if int(x) == num:
    print("Good Job!")
    break
  else:
    print("Nope")
</py-script>
```